# Expo not showing errors

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi in my node modules I have a number of errors involving proptypes. When connecting my device to expo and running the app, it would just present the error as  not showing me the directory of where the error is coming from, is there any other way to show where the error is coming from?

[image: Error Mess]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to shake your device (strongly)? There should pop up a window in which you can set up several debugging options. Maybe you can find some helpful options there!

But maybe it won´t fix that particular issue, because the problem for errors that occur on runtime, the links to the original files might not exist any more. The files have been minified, glued together, modified and all the stuff react does to create the app and in that process the informations gets lost.

My solution to this is somehow unsatisfying (I know), but maybe it helps: try to save and compile as often as possible, so that you can narrow the error range down to a few lines or at least the file.

As of compile errors the error messages are much better (but still way worse than in other languages): In between all the gibberish there are some filenames and line numbers.

Much better is the information in the console instead of the device:
[image]

Console: Helpful

[image]

Device: Not very helpful